# How to alter any attribute value in the json object using java code

Tags: java, json

I want to replace the attribute value from the below JSON file using java code.

JSON:

```
{
  "featureName": "F1",
  "featureVersion": "V1",
  "fingerprint": 
  {
    "criteria": 
     {
      "name": "Hostname",
      "selector": "0x8",
      "item":
      {
        "rawValue": "myComputer",
        "hashValue": "d44fd4dc365481"
        }
     }
  }

}
```

I want to change value of the featureName attribute, selector attribute, and hashvalue attribute. How to change the value of any attribute from jsonObject given above.

Comment: Yes. To both questions.

Answer (score 0):

> is [there] some other way to do it

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you could use a filter (i.e. program) like this:

```
.featureName = "newfn"
| .fingerprint.criteria.selector = "newcs"
| .fingerprint.criteria.item.hashValue = "newhv"
```

### DRY-er

```
.featureName = "newfn"
| .fingerprint.criteria
  |= (.selector = "newcs" | .item.hashValue = "newhv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `JSONObject` first by reading from the file. Then, You can construct a new `JSONObject` from the existing one(Or even modify the existing one, your wish), and write it back to the file.

Implementation specific details are [here](https://crunchify.com/json-manipulation-in-java-examples/).

However, this needs severe IO operations and would not work for huge files, you may get OOM errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject (org.json)

Code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(urJsonStr);

JSONObject fingerprintObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("fingerprint");

JSONObject itemObj = fingerprintObj.getJSONObject("item");

itemObj.put("hashValue", "new value");

fingerprintObj.put("item", itemObj);

fingerprintObj.put("selector", "new value");

jsonObject.put("fingerprint", fingerprintObj);

jsonObject.put("featureName", "new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

JSON:

```
String jsonString = {
  "featureName": "F1",
  "featureVersion": "V1",
  "fingerprint": 
  {
    "criteria": 
     {
      "name": "Hostname",
      "selector": "0x8",
      "item":
      {
        "rawValue": "myComputer",
        "hashValue": "d44fd4dc365481"
        }
     }
  }

}
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String jsonResult1 = (String)jsonResult.getString("jsonResult");
String jsonResult1 = jsonResult1.replace("F1","your data");
JSONObject fingerprintObj = (JSONObject)jsonResult.getJSONObject("fingerprint");
JSONObject criteria = (JSONObject)fingerprintObj.getJSONObject("criteria");
String hashValue =(String)criteria.getStirng("hashValue");
String hashValue = hashValue.replace("d44fd4dc365481","newdata");
```